# Error: event is undefined in case of dynamically populating table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which I create dynamically via javascript -

```
function populateTable(data) {

    const responseLength = data.length;

    if (responseLength) {

        var col = [];

            col.push("S. No.");

            for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                for (var key in data[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1 && key == "name") {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }

            col.push(" ");

            var table = document.createElement("table");

            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var i=0; i<col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");

                if (col[i] == "name") {
                    th.innerHTML = "Name";
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                } else {
                    th.innerHTML = col[i];
                    tr.appendChild(th);
                }
            }

            for (var i=data.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                for (var j=0; j<col.length; j++) {
                    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);

                    if (j == 0) {
                        tabCell.innerHTML = ((data.length-1) - i)+1;
                    } else if (j == 2) {
                        tabCell.id = data[i].id;
                        tabCell.style.textDecoration = "underline";
                        tabCell.style.cursor = "pointer";
                        tabCell.addEventListener('click', deleteSubCategory, false)
                        tabCell.innerHTML = "Delete";
                    } else {
                        tabCell.innerHTML = data[i][col[j]];
                    }
                }
            }

            var divContainer = document.getElementById("subCategoriesTable");
            divContainer.innerHTML = "";
            divContainer.appendChild(table);
    }
}
```

The table is places inside a form -

```
<div id="section-two">
    <div class="at-form">
        <form id="edit-categories-form">
            <label id="category-label">Category Name:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="category" value="" required placeholder="Ex. Class V"><br>

            <label id="sub-category-label">Add Sub-Category (multiple names can be comma separated):</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="sub-category" value="" required placeholder="Ex. History, English, Maths"><br>

            <label>Existing Sub-Categories:</label><br>
            <div id="subCategoriesTable"></div><br><br>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Done">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Function called when `click` event occurs -

```
function deleteSubCategory(event) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.id;
    deleteSubCategory(id);
}
```

However, I get the following error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: event is undefined
    deleteSubCategory http://localhost:8080/js/categories/editcategory.js:144
    deleteSubCategory http://localhost:8080/js/categories/editcategory.js:145
    populateTable http://localhost:8080/js/categories/editcategory.js:79
    getLinkedSubCategories http://localhost:8080/js/categories/editcategory.js:112
    async* http://localhost:8080/js/categories/editcategory.js:14
    EventListener.handleEvent* http://localhost:8080/js/categories/editcategory.js:1
```

I have other pages where I use the same approach and it is working as intended. However, in this particular case it is failing. Any idea where things could be going wrong?

Comment: `deleteSubCategory` is a recursive function (it calls itself). The first time, it gets passed an `event`. It extracts an `id` from that event, then calls itself with that `id`. Then, it tries to extract an id from that `id`. It gets `undefined`. It calls itself again, with `undefined`, and then, `(undefined).currentTarget` causes the error

Comment: This is correct. Please answer so as I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function deleteSubCategory(event) {
  var id = event.currentTarget.id;
  deleteSubCategory(id);
}
```

Here, `deleteSubCategory` is a recursive function (it calls itself).

- The first time, it gets passed an `event`. It extracts an `id` from that event, then calls itself with that `id`.
- Then, it tries to extract an id from that `id`. It gets `undefined`. It calls itself again, with `undefined`
- Then, `(undefined).currentTarget` causes the error